# Broadcasting assignment with advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Scratching my head about this assignment, which does not behave as expected:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
b = np.array([-1,-2,-3])
c = np.array([1])
a[...,c] = b
=> ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,4,3)
```

I expected

1. The indexing result shape to be (4,3,1) instead of (1,4,3), and
2. The right side shape of (3,) to actually be broadcastable to (1,4,3)?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first expectation is True. If you try `a[...,c].shape` it is 4,3,1. Not sure why the error says 1,3,4.

For the second expectation, you are assigning a vector (1D) of size 3 to a 3-D matrix (4,3,1). To do this, you need to make the vector `b` 2-D of shape (3,1). This can be done:

```
a[...,c] = b[None].T
```

See [Numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html?spm=5176.100239.blogcont204352.23.Ms4Xky)

Comment: So it seems to be an issue with the error message text only. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Indexing with `[:, None]` changes the orientation of the array.

```
a[...,c] = b[:, None]
```